# R: aggregate Cobb-Douglas Production Function estimation with trends and constrained coefficients

Tags: r, optimization, lm, mle

I aim at estimating the following equation in R:

Y_t = const + alpha_1 * (labor_t + theta_1 * trend1_t + theta_2 * trend2_t) + (1 - alpha_1) * capital_t

I tried the following:

```
library(stats4)

LL <- function(par){
  beta0 <- par[1]
  alpha1 <- par[2]
  theta1 <- par[3]
  theta2 <- par[4]
  sigma2 <- par[5]
  
  rhs <- beta0 + alpha1 * (log_lab + theta1*t80 + theta2*t95) + (1-alpha1)*log_cap
  # rhs <- beta0 + alpha1 * log_lab + (1-alpha1)*log_cap
  lhs <- y
  
  rval <- sum(-lhs + dnorm(lhs, mean = rhs, sd = sqrt(sigma2), log = TRUE))
  
  return(-rval)
}

par0 = as.vector(c(4.5, 0.65, 0.0014, 0.0023, 0.01)) 

fit <- optim(par0, LL, hessian = TRUE, 
             method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0.00001, upper = 10)
summary(fit)
```

Unfortunately, I optain the following error: `Error in optim(par0, LL, hessian = TRUE, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 1e-05,  :  non-finite finite-difference value [5]`

I already tried different approaches using MLE() and other specifications, yet unsuccessful. How do I have to address the problem of estimating a least-squares regression with constrained coefficients, i.e. alpha_1 * beta_1 = 1, such that beta_1 == (1-alpha_1)?

Answer (score 0):

May be use the following linear model:

```
 Y1(t) = α0 + α1*L1(t) + β1*T(1,t) + β2*T(2,t)
 where
   Y1(t) = Y(t)-C(t)
   L1(t) = L(t)-C(t)
```

and then recover:

```
  θ1 = β1/α1
  θ2 = β2/α1
```

(Check the math if this is correct)

Comment: this is an interesting idea, yet it lacks to adress the main question, namely how to estimate a model where \beta_1 + \beta_2 = 1, or in my paricular case y = alpha_1 * l + (1-alpha_1) * k (when abstracting from the trends....

Comment: y = alpha_1 * l + (1-alpha_1) * k  ==> y = alpha_1 * l + k - alpha_1 * k ==> (y-k) = alpha_1 * l  - alpha_1 * k  ==> (y-k) = alpha_1 ( l - k)